# change a .bat file to omit extensions when listing files in win 7

Tags: script, batch-file

dir /b > filenames.txt Re named to .bat  gives me  file   names with ext, I want to list without extensions,  Any ideas anybody

Answer (score 0):

Extract from dir /?

> /B          Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).

This means it doesn't strip the file extension... not that it's hard

> for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b') do echo %%~nf >> filenames.txt